# js validation only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm having an issue with the code below where if I put an invalid email address in it will properly show the signUpWarning alert the first time but if I close that box and try the same invalid email it won't pop back up. Any ideas?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //if submit button is clicked
    $('#submit_btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        if (!is_valid_email(email)){
            $("#signUpWarning").show();
        }else{

            $.ajax({
                url: "process.php",
                type: "post",
                data: "email=" + email,
                success: function() {
                    $("#signUpWarning").hide();
                    $("#signUpAlert").show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

function is_valid_email (email)
{
    return /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email);
}
```

The code for the alert box is:

```
  <div class="alert alert-block alert-error hide" id="signUpWarning"><!--Use: $("#signUpWarning").show(); to show this alert-->
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <h5 class="alert-heading">Sorry!</h5>&nbsp;Your e-mail address was not valid, please try again.
  </div>
```

Comment: can you give the code of the popu box? Maybe there is something wrong there.. ? (this code looks fine for me)

Comment: Thanks Mat, got it added to the post. It's strange that it will show the alert the first time and not for subsequent invalid entries. Also, after one invalid entry it will properly hide the warning and show the success alert.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps how you close the alert popup causes it to be removed from the DOM instead of hiding it.  Considering you say it shows success on a proper email after an improper one.  Also, you can test if the issue is in this code by sprinkling a console.log("something informative") before you go to show the error.  Personally I'd suggest doing console.log($("#signUpWarning")) to see if the element is there like you expect it to be.

Comment: Great call MushinNoShin, the div is gone after the first firing. The alert has an X to close it, I'll check into that to see if it's doing a .remove() on the div.

Comment: That's exactly what it is. jquery/bootstrap use .remove() to get rid of the alert - making it inaccessible for future use. Thanks @MushinNoShin!

Comment: might be a good idea to move `e.preventDefault();` call at the end of your jQuery click function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you're not removing the element from the DOM when closing the alert.

`console.log($("#signUpWarning"));` before the `$("#signUpWarning").show();` should help determine if that's what's happening.

Comment: Yes, this was it. I'm using jquery/bootstrap and the alert box's X in the upper right to close is tied to a .remove instead of .hide. Thanks @MushinNoShin!